# As a newbie in Data Science, should I learn the main python language first or should I learn it's libraries

Tags: python

I'm currently learning as a beginner and I need guidance. Thank you

Comment: There's no point learning libraries before you know the basics of the language.

Comment: I would learn python as a whole, but focus on the libraries relevant to data science as you get past the base python data types, control flows, functions and such.

Answer (score 1):

why not both? The libraries are quite simple/similar and you can feel more motivated during the process of learning python. I would recommend starting with sklearn. If you find this difficult you can try to learn python first.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time just picking up a "Teach yourself whatever" book and learning a new language like that.  I *have* been successful in picking up what I need to know in order to do a project, and then using that as a base for further understanding.  While syntax changes, principles of programming are constant.

So, if it wuz me, I'd just pick a project and learn what I need to make it work.  There are all sorts of resources for solving "how do I do X in this language" issues.  By the time you've finished a reasonably simple project, you'll have the basic syntax down and will have command of a couple of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I have started learning in **datacamp**. It was pretty helpful for me. In datacamp, there are a lot of courses and an environment to practice with real-world data.

https://app.datacamp.com/learn

**Some courses you may find helpful:**

1. Introduction to Data Science in Python
2. Introduction to Python
3. Intermediate Python

**If you have any particular career in mind, then you choose any course from the:**

1. Python Programmer
2. Data Analyst with python
3. Machine Learning Scientist with python
4. Data Engineer with python
5. Data Scientist with python

> All of them you will find at Datacamp.

**Another youtube playlist:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPrmA1SEN2k&list=PLZoTAELRMXVNUL99R4bDlVYsncUNvwUBB